# Download JSON files from an API and conver them to text

Tags: java

i am trying to write a program that would download specific files from an API and converts them from json to a text file, i am trying to do this in java but i have no experience in this language, does anyone have any suggestions on a simple way to do this and what programming language should i use to achieve this

Comment: Stack overflow is a place to help you with your concrete implementation, so search for your problem in a search engine and try it yourself. If you have a concrete problem you can come back and post it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so JavaScript would be the natural choice here, especially if the API you download from presents a link to the JSON file and the conversion is simple. You don't even need an IDE or a separate compiler, just a text editor and a browser.

Learn about JavaScript asynchronous programming with promises, then you can use the straightforward fetch API, see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

While you can use JSON in most languages, including Java, it would be overkill for such a task and there is absolutely no reason for you to learn Java for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://....");// location of api request
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
getRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

BufferedReader br =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String output;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
  builder.append(output);
}
br.close();
```

now you can do with string builder what you need